# The past perfect tense and simple past

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

We usually use when with reference to the simple past tense because it refers to a point of time rather than a period of time.

> When I reached the station, the train had left.

But can I say

> When porter had opened the door, we entered.

Are the following two sentences grammatical

> The porter had opened the gate and we entered.
>
> The porter opened the gate and we entered.

Is it a rule, that when we use conjunction ***and*** both the clauses must be be in the same form?

Answer (score 0):

When I reached the station, the train had left.

AND

When porter had opened the door, we entered.

Both the sentences are correct because past perfect shows an action that happened before something in the past, no matter whether we use it in the first-half or the second-half of a sentence.

The sentence- "The porter had opened the gate and we entered" :

This sentence is not grammatical because the rule of thumb is : Use the Past Perfect only when it is required to show that a certain action happened before something else.

The sentence: 
"The porter opened the gate and we entered" :

is sufficient for this purpose because the Simple Past before & after 'and' is perfectly showing the chronology.